# What is $dF(z)$ in the expected utility framework?

Tags: probability-distributions, definition, economics, utility

Background: from a Microeconomics course,

> $F$ is a cdf. In other words, if $F$ has a density function $f$, then 
>   $$F(z)={\int_{-\infty}^z f(x) dx}  $$
>
> Write the Bernoulli utility function $u: \mathbb R_+ \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that the preference is represented by
>   $$U(F) = \int u(z) dF(z)$$
>
> If $F$ has density $f$, then $U(F) = \int u(z) f(z)dz$

I am unfamiliar with the notation $dF(z)$, and don't quite understand what this means. Can someone help?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: I remember reading about this in Rudin but never made the connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two lines of your quote tells you what $dF(z)$ is:
$$
dF(z) = f(z)dz.
$$

In your application, $f$ is the probability density on (point) events, $u$ is the utility, and the integral $U$ calculates the expected utility on subsets as a weighted average of point utilities with weights the probabilities.